# EJB Entity: database row is automatically updated from Entity without save in EJB

Tags: java, ejb

The method loads a user entity bean from the database and returns it, but before doing that clears the password (setting it with null). The issue is that in the database itself the password is set with null, even though I don't have a `merge` or any other method that updates the entity. Any ideas?

```
public UserEntity loadFromDB (int userid) throws NotFoundException {

    UserEntity user = em.find(UserEntity.class, userid);
    if (user == null)
        throw new NotFoundException(); 

    user.setPassword(null);  

    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the method `loadFromDB`  is called within a transaction and so your Entity is `attached` and getting saved when transaction is closed.

Your DAO or service layer has transaction marked at class level and so the method is within a transaction.

If your method is part of transaction then it is basically adding below at start and end of transaction and it will commit updates to all the entities within transaction.

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

// updates to entity

entityManager.getTransaction().commit(); //Saves all updates to DB
```

You can avoid it by doing that update outside your transaction in your view layer or by marking that method as not being part of transaction.

Mark your method as not part of transcation by adding

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
```

Comment: thanks, the DAO class is invoked from a Stateless session bean and there's no update instruction or begin transaction anywhere.

Comment: UserEntity user = em.find(UserEnt.class, userid); tells me that it is running in a transaction

Comment: It must be running in a transaction, because I set the method with `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)` as you indicated and the row is not updated anymore. using `find` means that you initiate a transaction? I just need to load the row.

Comment: So whenever I have a read-only method (i.e. record is loaded with no updates needed) I need to indicate `explicitly` to the container not to initiate a transaction?

Comment: EJB will treat your Entities as your database row , any update to Entity in transaction is posted to database. You can keep your read-only method in transactions , but the methods are not read-only as you are updating the entity. If you don't mean to update the entity in database then keep these updates outside EJB methods.